# dplyr mutate on range of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to make an operation on a range of columns on a data frame. Let us say this dataset is:

```
set.seed(15)
df <- data.frame(id=letters[1:10], matrix(runif(5*10), nrow=5)) %>% dplyr::rename(O6 = X7)
```

I think that it is quite obvious what I want to achieve with:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = min(X3:X8))
```

ie to get the result of:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = min(X3, X4, X5, O6, X7, X8))
```

My initial try with X3:X8 doesn't give any error message, so I am wondering:
1. What is the best way to achieve the desired output using dplyr (that I get the min/max/average etc. value from columns X3 to X8)
2. What am I actually getting when using X3:X8

Many thanks !

Ps. it would be great if the solution to this includes a possibility to also do:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minval_all_but_ex_rownames = min(-id))
```

Comment: I think the range of columns (`X3:X8`) works in `select` but not within the functions called within a `mutate` or related function. (I'm interested to learn if somebody knows differently.)

Comment: @r2evans I found the following resource where it is indicated that you cannot use `select` within `mutate`. There is an unofficial "solution" on that page. However, when I tried it for this context, it failed to work: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2050

Comment: Hello r2evans. I did not immediately realize that this was my task to assign what I thought was the "best" answer, I thought that this was selected by the community based on the upvotes. Thanks for the hint. Many thanks to everybody, I learned from every solution proposed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your questions (1) the code in the question is acting the same as:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = min(X3))
```

or just

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = X3)
```

and for question (2) in (1) below we rework your solution so that it works and following that provide a few other dplyr and base solutions.  In the solutions below we have shown the result for `min` and `max`.  These can readily be extended in the obvious way for additional statistics such as `mean`, `sd`, `median`, etc. by adding arguments to `mutate` or `summarize` or extending the `aggregate` function.  *Note that the solutions below all work with simple `min`, `max`, etc. which makes it easier to extend to additional statistics.*  Solutions which make use of `pmin` instead of `min` may be harder to extend because there may not be a ready counterpart to `pmin` for every statistic you want.

**1) modify code in question** To rework your solution we can use `do`.  Within `do` a dot will refer to the current group, in this case the current row, but it will be a list so convert back to data frame.  Note that we used `{...}` within the `do` to prevent the dot within `{...}` from referring to the current row as a list but instead to refer to `data.frame(.)` .

```
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   do(as.data.frame(.) %>% { 
      subs <- select(., X3:X8)
      mutate(., Min = subs %>% min,
                Max = subs %>% max) 
      } ) %>%
   ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 13
   id       X1    X2    X3    X4     X5    X6    O6    X8    X9    X10    Min   Max
 * <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a     0.602 0.989 0.105 0.842 0.804  0.659 0.499 0.658 0.915 0.429  0.105  0.842
 2 b     0.195 0.815 0.646 0.447 0.793  0.107 0.257 0.122 0.457 0.330  0.107  0.793
 3 c     0.966 0.254 0.509 0.965 0.358  0.148 0.492 0.516 0.921 0.753  0.148  0.965
 4 d     0.651 0.687 0.707 0.141 0.0580 0.928 0.117 0.302 0.259 0.844  0.0580 0.928
 5 e     0.367 0.831 0.862 0.777 0.566  0.476 0.513 0.760 0.344 0.0109 0.476  0.862
 6 f     0.602 0.989 0.105 0.842 0.804  0.659 0.499 0.658 0.915 0.429  0.105  0.842
 7 g     0.195 0.815 0.646 0.447 0.793  0.107 0.257 0.122 0.457 0.330  0.107  0.793
 8 h     0.966 0.254 0.509 0.965 0.358  0.148 0.492 0.516 0.921 0.753  0.148  0.965
 9 i     0.651 0.687 0.707 0.141 0.0580 0.928 0.117 0.302 0.259 0.844  0.0580 0.928
10 j     0.367 0.831 0.862 0.777 0.566  0.476 0.513 0.760 0.344 0.0109 0.476  0.862
```

**2) apply** Using `apply`:

```
df %>% {
  Apply <- function(fun) select(., X3:X8) %>% apply(1, fun)
  mutate(., Min = Apply(min), Max = Apply(max))
}
```

**2a) base R** or with just base R:

```
Apply <- function(fun) apply(subset(df, select = X3:X8), 1, fun)
transform(df, Min = Apply(min), Max = Apply(max))
```

**3) dplyr/tidyr** Another possibility is dplyr with tidyr reshaping `df` to long form, performing the calculation in long form and then joining back to `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   left_join({
     gather(., key, value, -id) %>%
     filter(between(key, "X3", "X8")) %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     summarize(Min = min(value), Max = max(value)) %>%
     ungroup
   })
```

**3a) Base R** (3) can be done in R base R using `reshape` to create a long form data frame, `subset` to reduce it to X3:X8  and merge to perform the join.

```
long <- reshape(df, dir = "long", varying = list(names(df)[-1]), 
  times = names(df)[-1], v.names = "min")
subs <- subset(long, time >= "X3" & time <= "X8")
merge(df, aggregate(min ~ id, subs, function(x) c(Min = min(x), Max = max(x))))
```

**4) dplyr/purrr**  This one is similar  to (2) except we use `purrr::pmap_dbl` instead of `apply`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% {
  Pmap <- function(fun) select(., X3:X8) %>% pmap_dbl(~ fun(c(...)))
  mutate(., Min = Pmap(min), Max = Pmap(max))
}
```

### Updates

Have made some improvements and added additional solutions.

Comment: I didn't know `subset(..., select=)` allowed colon-ranging, awesome.

Answer (score 4):

`dplyr::select` can use the range-notation of `X3:X7`, but not other functions. If you can work outside of `mutate`, try this:

```
df$minval_X3_X8 <- do.call(pmin, select(df, X3:X8))
df
#    id        X1        X2        X3        X4         X5        O6        X7        X8        X9       X10 minval_X3_X8
# 1   a 0.6021140 0.9888592 0.1046694 0.8417851 0.80372740 0.6590069 0.4985587 0.6578783 0.9152619 0.4291725   0.10466936
# 2   b 0.1950439 0.8151934 0.6461509 0.4474437 0.79334595 0.1069735 0.2567427 0.1215491 0.4574306 0.3302786   0.10697354
# 3   c 0.9664587 0.2539684 0.5090904 0.9646670 0.35756312 0.1483839 0.4916694 0.5159349 0.9210739 0.7528325   0.14838386
# 4   d 0.6509055 0.6872308 0.7066286 0.1411871 0.05800106 0.9277570 0.1174759 0.3016811 0.2591188 0.8438981   0.05800106
# 5   e 0.3670719 0.8314290 0.8623137 0.7767125 0.56574614 0.4763697 0.5128062 0.7603278 0.3437781 0.0108724   0.47636970
# 6   f 0.6021140 0.9888592 0.1046694 0.8417851 0.80372740 0.6590069 0.4985587 0.6578783 0.9152619 0.4291725   0.10466936
# 7   g 0.1950439 0.8151934 0.6461509 0.4474437 0.79334595 0.1069735 0.2567427 0.1215491 0.4574306 0.3302786   0.10697354
# 8   h 0.9664587 0.2539684 0.5090904 0.9646670 0.35756312 0.1483839 0.4916694 0.5159349 0.9210739 0.7528325   0.14838386
# 9   i 0.6509055 0.6872308 0.7066286 0.1411871 0.05800106 0.9277570 0.1174759 0.3016811 0.2591188 0.8438981   0.05800106
# 10  j 0.3670719 0.8314290 0.8623137 0.7767125 0.56574614 0.4763697 0.5128062 0.7603278 0.3437781 0.0108724   0.47636970
```

---

**Edit**: as @Moody_Mudskipper suggested, this can be included in a `mutate`:

```
df %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = do.call(pmin, select(., X3:X8)))
# same output as above
```

But this should be used with caution, since its use does not honor `group`ing of the data. I use this next methodology periodically to see what my functions "see" when called within (optionally-`group`ed) `mutate`. The `mymin` function here does absolutely nothing useful, just provides a mid-`mutate` browse:

```
mymin <- function(...) { browser(); 1; }
```

The example:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = do.call(mymin, select(., X3:X8)))
# Called from: (function (...) 
# {
#     browser()
#     1
# }) ...snip...
# Browse[1]> 
# debug at #1: [1] 1
# Browse[2]>
```

If we look at the function's arguments, we'll see what it has been provided:

```
list(...)
# $X3
#  [1] 0.1046694 0.6461509 0.5090904 0.7066286 0.8623137 0.1046694 0.6461509 0.5090904 0.7066286
# [10] 0.8623137
# $X4
#  [1] 0.8417851 0.4474437 0.9646670 0.1411871 0.7767125 0.8417851 0.4474437 0.9646670 0.1411871
# [10] 0.7767125
# $X5
#  [1] 0.80372740 0.79334595 0.35756312 0.05800106 0.56574614 0.80372740 0.79334595 0.35756312
#  [9] 0.05800106 0.56574614
# $O6
#  [1] 0.6590069 0.1069735 0.1483839 0.9277570 0.4763697 0.6590069 0.1069735 0.1483839 0.9277570
# [10] 0.4763697
# $X7
#  [1] 0.4985587 0.2567427 0.4916694 0.1174759 0.5128062 0.4985587 0.2567427 0.4916694 0.1174759
# [10] 0.5128062
# $X8
#  [1] 0.6578783 0.1215491 0.5159349 0.3016811 0.7603278 0.6578783 0.1215491 0.5159349 0.3016811
# [10] 0.7603278
```

Had this honored the `rowwise` grouping, I would have expected to see something like this, representing just one row of the data:

```
lapply(list(...), `[`, 1)
# $X3
# [1] 0.1046694
# $X4
# [1] 0.8417851
# $X5
# [1] 0.8037274
# $O6
# [1] 0.6590069
# $X7
# [1] 0.4985587
# $X8
# [1] 0.6578783
```

Comment: This is the best option I believe, and we can do `df %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = do.call(pmin, select(., X3:X8)))` as well if we prefer a pipe chain.

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper, good point. Edited to include that (plus a caution).

Answer (score 4):

With `tidyverse`, we can do

**1)**  With `reduce` and `pmin`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(X3:X8) %>% 
  reduce(pmin) %>% 
  mutate(df, minval_X3_X8 = .)
# id        X1        X2        X3        X4         X5        X6        O6
#1   a 0.6021140 0.9888592 0.1046694 0.8417851 0.80372740 0.6590069 0.4985587
#2   b 0.1950439 0.8151934 0.6461509 0.4474437 0.79334595 0.1069735 0.2567427
#3   c 0.9664587 0.2539684 0.5090904 0.9646670 0.35756312 0.1483839 0.4916694
#4   d 0.6509055 0.6872308 0.7066286 0.1411871 0.05800106 0.9277570 0.1174759
#5   e 0.3670719 0.8314290 0.8623137 0.7767125 0.56574614 0.4763697 0.5128062
#6   f 0.6021140 0.9888592 0.1046694 0.8417851 0.80372740 0.6590069 0.4985587
#7   g 0.1950439 0.8151934 0.6461509 0.4474437 0.79334595 0.1069735 0.2567427
#8   h 0.9664587 0.2539684 0.5090904 0.9646670 0.35756312 0.1483839 0.4916694
#9   i 0.6509055 0.6872308 0.7066286 0.1411871 0.05800106 0.9277570 0.1174759
#10  j 0.3670719 0.8314290 0.8623137 0.7767125 0.56574614 0.4763697 0.5128062
#          X8        X9       X10 minval_X3_X8
#1  0.6578783 0.9152619 0.4291725   0.10466936
#2  0.1215491 0.4574306 0.3302786   0.10697354
#3  0.5159349 0.9210739 0.7528325   0.14838386
#4  0.3016811 0.2591188 0.8438981   0.05800106
#5  0.7603278 0.3437781 0.0108724   0.47636970
#6  0.6578783 0.9152619 0.4291725   0.10466936
#7  0.1215491 0.4574306 0.3302786   0.10697354
#8  0.5159349 0.9210739 0.7528325   0.14838386
#9  0.3016811 0.2591188 0.8438981   0.05800106
#10 0.7603278 0.3437781 0.0108724   0.47636970
```

---

**2)** Or convert the column names to symbols and do an evaluation

```
df %>% 
   mutate(minval_X3_X8 = pmin(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[3:8])))
```

Comment: The second line could be `do.call(pmin,.) %>%` or  `invoke(pmin,.) %>%` for added efficiency (similar to r2evans' solution).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `purrr::map` with `transpose`

```
df %>% mutate(minval_X3_X8 = map(transpose(select(., X3:X8)), ~min(as.numeric(.x))))
#id        X1        X2        X3        X4         X5        X6        O6
#1   a 0.6021140 0.9888592 0.1046694 0.8417851 0.80372740 0.6590069 0.4985587
#2   b 0.1950439 0.8151934 0.6461509 0.4474437 0.79334595 0.1069735 0.2567427
#3   c 0.9664587 0.2539684 0.5090904 0.9646670 0.35756312 0.1483839 0.4916694
#4   d 0.6509055 0.6872308 0.7066286 0.1411871 0.05800106 0.9277570 0.1174759
#5   e 0.3670719 0.8314290 0.8623137 0.7767125 0.56574614 0.4763697 0.5128062
#6   f 0.6021140 0.9888592 0.1046694 0.8417851 0.80372740 0.6590069 0.4985587
#7   g 0.1950439 0.8151934 0.6461509 0.4474437 0.79334595 0.1069735 0.2567427
#8   h 0.9664587 0.2539684 0.5090904 0.9646670 0.35756312 0.1483839 0.4916694
#9   i 0.6509055 0.6872308 0.7066286 0.1411871 0.05800106 0.9277570 0.1174759
#10  j 0.3670719 0.8314290 0.8623137 0.7767125 0.56574614 0.4763697 0.5128062
#       X8        X9       X10 minval_X3_X8
#1  0.6578783 0.9152619 0.4291725    0.1046694
#2  0.1215491 0.4574306 0.3302786    0.1069735
#3  0.5159349 0.9210739 0.7528325    0.1483839
#4  0.3016811 0.2591188 0.8438981   0.05800106
#5  0.7603278 0.3437781 0.0108724    0.4763697
#6  0.6578783 0.9152619 0.4291725    0.1046694
#7  0.1215491 0.4574306 0.3302786    0.1069735
#8  0.5159349 0.9210739 0.7528325    0.1483839
#9  0.3016811 0.2591188 0.8438981   0.05800106
#10 0.7603278 0.3437781 0.0108724    0.4763697
```

Comment: Oooh, I like `transpose`, thanks for demoing it! (This method honors `rowwise` implicitly due to how `map` works, a bonus.)

Comment: I very much like the simplicity of this solution. Unfortunately it does not work on my side... Any hint why? I get "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (list) of argument."

Comment: @Yvan You're right and I'm very confused;-) I get the same error even though (I think) it worked earlier, on a different machine. Either way, I've fixed the error, perhaps try again, we need an additional `as.numeric` (to collapse the nested `list` structure from `transpose`). Not quite as neat, but still very short.